# How to sent a POST(request payload) with text/plain content type using Python-Requests?

Tags: python, python-requests

The case is that I met a post request, the `Content-Type` is `text/plain`, the request data is not `Form Data`, but is `Request Payload`, I would like to know how can I post data correctly using python? especially in `requests`.

[image: Content-Type pic]

[image: Request Payload pic]

`Request payload` is a dict or text?

Comment: you can specify `content-type` of  you are sending `payload = {'some': 'data'}
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)`

Comment: It doesn't work. as the Request Payload pic, do you think it is a dict and divided by **'='**?

Comment: are you posting image

Comment: yes, I only could post the link

Comment: As the pic, how I should manager the data form in file? key-value? text?

Comment: pic data treated as `text`

Comment: this is a part of image data in a request `{u'file': u'data:application/octet-stream;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgAAAQABAAD/7QA2UGhvdG9zaG9wIDMuMAA4QklNBAQAAAAAABkcAmcAFFpwTTBIWDB3ak5VdDQxY3RjWm5XAP/iAhxJQ0NfUFJPRklMRQABAQAAAgxsY21zAhAAAG1udHJSR0IgWFlaIAfcAAEAGQADACkAOWFjc3BBU.....'}`

Comment: Add the code into your question, not links to images.

Answer (score -1):

Try to send request without specifying `headers` like:

```
payload = {"callcount": 1,
           "c0-scriptname": "newLoginDwr",
           ...
           "xml": true}
requests.post(url, data=payload)
```